# How do I create a cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift2, uibarbuttonitem

I am having troubles getting my cancel button to work. I have this action connected to my cancel button and I plan to dismiss the view controller like so:

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I was wondering what obvious bit I am missing. (This is a bar button item for a table view).

Comment: Have you added the bar button item in the table view or on the navigation bar?

Comment: Are your views using a `navigationController`? You could try `navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` although this wouldn't work if the view was presented modally.

Comment: The above code will attempt to dismiss a child view controller that was presented modally. I added an answer to explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "Cancel clicked")
```

If you wanted the method to take the sender as a parameter, you would put a colon at the end:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "CancelClicked:")

func CancelClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```

Comment: where you assign this var b , write  your code fully

Comment: Can I assign the button as an outlet?

Answer (score 1):

After you add the NavigationBar (and Navigation Item) to the Storyboard using IB, the reference to navigationItem var will be automatically mapped to your ViewController file. Add the code below to attach a cancel button to the navigationItem to dismiss the modal View Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelClicked(sender:)))
}

func cancelClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Cancel clicked!")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with one little fix. Dismiss is called on the presenting controller. self.dismissViewController would dismiss child view controller presented by the current vc. but if you wanna dismiss the existing vc you should call dismiss on the parent

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is the VC presented modally?